# Different icons in dock for the same application (gnome-terminal)

Tags: gnome-terminal, dock

I have two gnome-terminal windows each one running ssh connected to a different remote server: SERVER A, and SERVER B.

Although using different `.desktop` settings for each one, dock groups them all together in only one icon, the gnome-terminal icon.

I would like to have them separated in two different applications with custom icons in dock, since I deal with them as if they were different applications, because they are connected to different servers accessing different end-user applications.

My current launching configuration file for the called "server a":

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e "ssh server-a"
Name=SERVER A
Icon=/home/me/custom/server-a.png
```

**EDIT:**
Ubuntu version: 22.04

Answer (score 3):

In the `.desktop` launcher, start your terminal with the `--class` option to change the WM_CLASS of its window to a unique name. In addition, link the launcher to that class by adding a `StartupWMClass=` line:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --class=server-a -e "ssh server-a"
Name=SERVER A
Icon=/home/me/custom/server-a.png
StartupWMClass=server-a
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It got so close, unfortunately the dock icon wasn't customized it still shows the gnome-terminal icon, and it doesn't show the small point indicating the amount of windows open (Ubuntu 22.04), there is no indicator of any open window, actually. Is there ways to fix or trick that?

Comment: The dock icon stays what it was. Remove it and replace it by your custom launcher.