# Using different dock entries for different applications launched with the same binary on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal, wayland, dock

The Gnome desktop dock (and other similar applications) use the window's `WM_CLASS` property to group windows, so different windows with the same class will be grouped together under the same dock icon. Sometimes this is unwanted; most commonly, when `gnome-terminal` is used to launch various terminal-based applications. E.g. I have a dock icon to open IRC; I want the newly created window to be grouped under that icon, not the terminal icon.

Traditionally, the solution was to use either the `--class` command line parameter that many different frameworks provide, or some hack (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650865/set-wm-class-with-wnck-xprop-or-something-else)) to change the window class. But 1) with the [deprecation of `set_wmclass()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Window.set_wmclass.html) those `--class` parameters are increasingly removed or broken (e.g. `gnome-terminal` has such a parameter but it doesn't seem to do anything); 2) with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS switching from X11 to Wayland as default in most cases, none of the previous hacks to change `WM_CLASS` work. The Wayland equivalent to the window class seems to be the [app ID](https://wayland-book.com/xdg-shell-basics/xdg-toplevel.html), but AIUI the functionality [to change it](https://wayland.app/protocols/xdg-shell#xdg_toplevel:request:set_app_id) is not exposed outside the application the way it is in X11.

Is there a better way to set the window class, or to influence dock grouping in some other way?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411410/different-icons-in-dock-for-the-same-application-gnome-terminal is a similar question, but the solution described there doesn't work at all. I can verify with e.g. the looking glass tool that `--class` doesn't actually set the `gnome-terminal` window's class.

Comment: Related bug reports: [gnome-terminal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7734), [terminator](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1695793)